# Change request parameters name - Laravel

Tags: laravel, request

is there anyway to change the parameters name of request in laravel?

something like :

```
//we have $request['email'] in our request object and we need to change the name of it NOT VALUE

ChangeParaName($request['email'],$request['password']);

//now instead of $request['email'] we have $request['password'] with same value in our request object and just name of parameter changed
```

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
$request->merge(['password' => $request->email]);
```

This will simply put a key called `password` in `$request` with value of `$request->email`.
The `email` key would still be there.

Comment: but it won't have the value of email

Comment: It will have the value of `email`.

Comment: @yosober, If you see the array we are merging, it's key is `password` and it's value is `$request->email`.

Answer (score 0):

There are two steps. First of all, you have to merge then you have to unset or remove the old request parameter name.

1. First merge the request
   `$request->merge(['password' => $request->email]);`
2. Remove request parameter name
   `$request->request->remove('email');`

I think it will help you.